Renew Lock Before It Get Expire For Long Running Process
I have this Service Bus trigger where I am trying to renew the lock before it expires. As per my knowledge, the maximum time-to-live for a message is 5 min. But my task is taking 20 min to complete it. So to tackle this situation I made the below changes in my host.json file
"messageHandlerOptions": {
  "autoComplete": false,
  "maxConcurrentCalls": 300,
  "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:30:00"
}

In my receiver function I made the below changes to Renew the lock in every 4 minutes upto 25 minutes.
[Function("XmlProcessor")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = false)] string message, 
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage, 
    FunctionContext context)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"XmlProcessor triggered for message {message}");

    try
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25));
        var receiver = _client.CreateReceiver("trmxmlprocessor");
        Task renewLockTask = RenewLock(receiver, receivedMessage, cts.Token);
        await _initializer.Start(message);
        await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(receivedMessage);
        cts.Cancel();
        renewLockTask.Dispose();
        _logger.LogInformation($"XmlProcessor completed for message: {message}");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"XmlProcessor root exception: {ex}");
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Processing failed. Further retries are not allowed.", ex);
    }
    _logger.LogInformation($"XmlProcessor completed for message: {message}");
}

//Renew Lock Method
private async Task RenewLock(ServiceBusReceiver receiver, ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage, CancellationToken token)
{
    var renewalBuffer = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4), token);
            await receiver.RenewMessageLockAsync(receivedMessage,token);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Lock Renewed");
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to renewing lock");
        }
    }
}

But I am always getting exception at await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(receivedMessage); Because I am always getting my ServiceBusReceivedMessage as null.

Hi, did my response resolve your issues with the Azure Function?

When using Azure Function Service Bus Triggers, the trigger handles the ServiceBusClient and its receiver under the hood. For more info, see this answer to my question from a few years back. This means that you probably don't want to use the ServiceBusClient (_client) to create a new receiver. I.e. by using a trigger, you've already got a receiver under the hood. This, and some other factors means that you'll probably have to switch out some of the methods you're using to deal with the received message.
Message Binding
Firstly, the reason your ServiceBusReceivedMessage is null is because the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute is placed on the string message parameter, instead of the ServiceBusReceivedMessage parameter. I'd suggest removing the string, and sticking only to the ServiceBusReceivedMessage. ServiceBusReceivedMessage it richer in information, and you can still access the message body, as a string, through the ServiceBusReceivedMessage. Another pro is that you can perform actions on a ServiceBusReceivedMessage.
Message Actions
It looks like your trigger lives in an out-of-process Azure Functions App, based on the FunctionAttribute you've put on your Service Bus Trigger method. By default, messages are completed when the trigger has successfully executed. This can be disabled, either by disabling the AutoCompleteMessages flag in host.json, or on the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute. Once it's disabled, instead of using
await receiver.CompleteMessageAsync(receivedMessage)

to complete the message, bind the ServiceBusMessageActions as a method parameter, and use
await actions.CompleteMessageAsync(receivedMessage);

(However, note that the ServiceBusMessageActions firstly became bindable for the out-of-process trigger in the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus package version 5.14.0. Older versions of the worker does not allow for message actions.)
Lock Renewal
Finally, when using a Service Bus Trigger, a message that's not finished processing will have its lock auto-renewed, up until maxAutoRenewDuration is reached. This removes your need for manually calling
await receiver.RenewMessageLockAsync(receivedMessage,token);

The upper bound for a message's time-to-live is not limited to 5 minutes, but it can be limited by your Service Bus Plan, the message sender, and the limits set on the Queue, Topic and/or Subscription. Read more here.
Although the time-to-live is not limited to 5 minutes, the timeout of your Azure Functions can be, by default. This timeout limit can be increased, depending on the Hosting Plan of your Functions App. See limits here. You can set the global function timeout for your Functions app in the host.json file, as follows:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
}

The rule to follow is to have maxAutoRenewDuration be greater or equal to functionTimeout, see why here.
I've not focused on the RenewLock() method, and if you fix the other things, it should not be needed. But one thing to think about is what would happen if you start the renew task and don't have any other thread left to run that process on. Will it work as intended?
Putting It All Together
Combining everything, your Trigger would look something like this:
[Function("XmlProcessor")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "AzureServiceBusConnectionString", IsSessionsEnabled = false, AutoCompleteMessages = false)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage, 
    ServiceBusMessageActions actions, 
    FunctionContext context)
{
    var messageBody = receivedMessage.Body.ToString();
    _logger.LogInformation($"XmlProcessor triggered for message: {messageBody}");

    try
    { 
        await _initializer.Start(messageBody);
        await actions.CompleteMessageAsync(receivedMessage);

        _logger.LogInformation($"XmlProcessor completed for message: {messageBody}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"XmlProcessor root exception: {ex}");
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Processing failed. Further retries are not allowed.", ex);
    }
    _logger.LogInformation($"XmlProcessor completed for message: {messageBody}");
}

and your host.json like this:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 300,
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:30:00"
            }
        }
    },
    "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
}


This can also happen if the server (Azure Service Bus) and the client application (Azure Function) have a time delay. This was the reason in my case. You can check this by setting the debug level of the Azure Function to Debug and looking for the log entry “Trigger details” after a message has been peeked.
Example:

Trigger details: MessageId: [xyz], SequenceNumber: [xyz], DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-12-18T11:28:22.5370000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-12-18T11:39:28.7600000+00:00, SessionId: [xyz]

In my configuration, I have a lock duration of 15 seconds configured on the Azure SB Queue, but due to a time gap between my local dev notebook (Hosted Azure Function in Visual Studio 2022) and the Azure SB, a renewal action never occurred for the message.
After I fixed the underlying time delay/gap between the systems, everything works as expected and described by @Isak Engström.
